# What's the difference between 'remove' and 'delete' in MongoDB updates?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm studying `MongoDB(mongoose)`.

So I've a question on `Model.findByIdAndRemove()` and `Model.findByIdAndDelete()` of `Mongoose` - what's the difference between both of them.

[mongoose-docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

What's the proper use of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findByIdAndDelete & findByIdAndRemove are same other than [findOneAndRemove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) uses findAndModify with remove functionality with time to execution of particular amount of operations.

by doing comparison findByIdAndDelete is always better than findByIdAndRemove.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to Understand.